# Как изменить словарь в зависимости от выбора пользователя

Tags: python

Программа при запуске спрашивает у пальзователя какие емейлы ему использовать

```
test@test.com - 1
test2@test.com - 2
test3@test.com - 3
```

пользователь вводит `1 3`

Как на базе выбора пользователя изменить словарь и массив?

```
 d1 = dict(name=name.rstrip(), company=co, email1 =name1, email2 =name2, email3 =name3, email4 =name4, email5 =name5, email6 =name6, email7 =name7, email8 =name8) 
  fieldnames = ['name', 'company', 'email1' , 'email2', 'email3', 'email4' , 'email5', 'email6', 'email7' , 'email8']
```

тоесть если пользователь выбрал 2 почты что бы словаь и массив содержал только `... email1 =name1, email2 =name2` не важно напишет пользователь 1 2 или 2 3 или 1 3
Мне на ум приходят только сложные проверки if, elif 
может есть какое то более красивое решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно реализовать как то так:

```
x = input('Введите значение: ')
e = {'1' : 'email1', '2' : 'email2'}
n = list()
for i in x.split(' '):
    n.append(e[i])
print(n)
```